# FB access token is empty without any FB exception thrown from PHP SDK v5

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am using modified example from Facebook developers page. My JS:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : '{xxx}',
    cookie     : true,  
    xfbml      : true,  
    version    : 'v2.8' 
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
});
};

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8&appId=xxx";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}
 function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,name,email'}, function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            console.log('Here is email: ' + response.email);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ='Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
    $.get(baseurl + 'index.php/auth/fb_login', function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.fb-login', function(){
        FB.login(function(response){
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});
    });
});
```

Basic idea is that after successful login I display response object in console and run `testAPI()` which makes API call and displays name and email in console. After that I added ajax call to `auth/fb_login`:

```
function fb_login(){
        require_once( 'vendor/autoload.php' );
        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
          'app_id'                => $this->config->item('app_id', 'tank_auth'),
          'app_secret'            => $this->config->item('app_secret', 'tank_auth'),
          'default_graph_version' => $this->config->item('default_graph_version', 'tank_auth')
        ]);

        $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
        try {
          $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
          exit;
        }
         
        if ($accessToken) {
          var_dump('Successfully logged in!');die();
        }
        var_dump(' not Successfully logged in!');die();
    }
```

And the `var_dump` always dumps "not ..." without any FB exceptions.

I used [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and it returns

`Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error.`

```
Application ID  xxx: MyAppName
User ID
xxx: Kārlis Janisels
User last installed this app via API v2.x
Issued  Unknown
Expires 1480410000 (in about an hour)
Valid   False
Origin  Unknown
Scopes  email, public_profile
```

So the underlining problem - I can get valid access token in browser but not in server.

If it helps - I am using codeigniter framework on wamp server localhost.